# Does encapsulating one CryptoStream in several others improve security?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cryptography

I'm working on a project for Windows Phone 7 which stores highly secure information. This data is protected with a password. If I encrypt one CryptoStream within 3 other CryptoStreams (a total of 4 cryptostreams embedded in each other, each using different methods to generate the key, initialization vector, and salt). Is this method secure enough, or do I need more  CryptoStreams (each one uses 256 bit AES encryption)?

Comment: *gets his tin foil hat* One can never have enough security!

Comment: does the tin foil stop the mind probes?

Comment: Have you ensured that the data stays protected while it is in-memory?  How do you get the data on the phone to begin with, and how do you access it?  How easy is it to get/guess a password (do you let them just pick any-old password, or do you have stringent requirements for contents and length?)  What if they forget the password?  You should focus on the whole lifetime and usage of your data, not just how secure it is while in a single stage of that lifetime.  Also, I haven't heard of anyone using this many levels of crypto on a single form/storage of the same data.

Comment: I have looked into in-memory encryption of the data, but the problem is; it has to eventually be decrypted to be displayed on the screen, so the user can read the information. The information on any system could be vulnerable at this stage, because of the fact that it has to eventually be stored (in RAM, and on the display/played through headphones) in an unencrypted form. If they forget the password, enter the emergency 'reset code', or enter an invalid password 3 times, the data will be deleted from the device.

Comment: You don't necessarily get more security by adding layers of encryption. *If* you know what you're doing you can. But then again if you know what you're doing you won't bother.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is far more likely someone will brute force or socially engineer the password than they would crack even a singly-encrypted stream since the password will generally have a smaller bitspace than the key.  All encrypting it multiple times does is increase the time or effort required to brute force the password by O(n) (you really want complexity to increase by O(n^2) or more).

But if you need super-secure encryption, don't roll your own strategy, pick a DOD standard (or equivalent) and implement it.

---

To explain further, AES is a block cipher with three different key lengths.  First part of the strategy is determining the key length you want to use.  You could pick one at random, or pick the largest, but you really want to pick the best choice for your situation.  Next is the actual usage of AES.  Since it's a block cipher it will encode the identical plaintext into identical ciphertext, so you will want to use an initialization vector and salt and other such techniques to ensure that plaintext will become different ciphertext.

Then there's how you derive the key from the password, that may be weak.  If you generate the key each time, you may have accidentally narrowed the keyspace and weakened it. You also have to take into account the random number generator that was used, as it may produce predictable values.  If you use the password to unlock the key storage in some way, then your data is only as protected as that key store.  If you fetch the key remotely only upon successful receipt of the password, then you've prevented off-line attacks of the data and can actively detect brute-force attacks.

Finally there's the aspect of the password itself, by far the weakest point of your encryption strategy.  It doesn't matter how many ciphers you use if the user picks a weak password. That's why even if you only encrypt the data with a single 128-bit AES encryption it's more likely that an attacker will attempt to compromise the password than try to break the encryption.

Picking a set of strategies that have been tested will serve you better than coming up with your own, unless you plan to spend the requisite money on penetration testing and security audits.

---

For fun, read up on how [TrueCrypt does it](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=encryption-scheme).

Comment: Yes, but how you are using AES is different than how the DOD uses AES.  If you encrypt something with AES and then post the key on Wikipedia you are using DOD-grade encryption but a substandard encryption strategy.

Comment: If every means of encrypting something was 'standard', then wouldn't that make the key easier to crack?

Comment: Also keep in mind that specific security protocols the DoD uses on their computers might not be applicable to Windows Phone 7, due to its reliance on managed code only, and not all 'standard' encryption libraries will run on it.

Comment: You are writing code for an insecure device.  Expect that your attacker is going to reverse engineer your application and find out exactly the methods you are using to encrypt your data -- they are not secret.  That being said, randomly deciding on four ways to encrypt your data is not going to guarantee security; picking a strategy that has been vetted by ??? math geniuses at the NSA to ensure maximum protection from attack is your best bet. It goes beyond just the algorithms used to include key derivation, key management, and other things.

Comment: I'll probably implement something which (as you mentioned, the random number generator may not be secure) implements a Pure Random Number generator through a secure web service that generates random numbers through radio signals, encrypts them with RSA+AES, then transmits them to the device. I will also (in order to prevent weak passwords) enforce a standard password strength as required by Windows Server 2008 R2, then use a hidden volume similar to how TrueCrypt does it, by providing fake data upon the entry of a certain other password, then clear the real encrypted data from the device.

Comment: @IDWMaster.  Having a "kill password" that deletes data is of dubious value.  Anyone looking to attack this system is FIRST going to make a copy and then only work on the copy.  If the user under duress provides a "kill password" and it deletes ANYTHING you just confirmed that A) more data exists and B) it is valuable enough to kill.  This is why truecrypt works on plausible deniability.  Each partition is independent and can only be verified and accessed with the password.  Say I have two partitions A & B.  If I only give you password A you have no evidence that partition B even exists.

Comment: @IDWMaster.  HAving standard encryption doesn't make it easier to crack.  Encryption isn't obscurity.  Good encryption stands up to an attack even if EVERY SINGLE DETAIL except the key is fully known by the attacker.  Ultimately the attack is likely to discover, reverse engineer, steal, and coerce every single detail of your system thus any "encryption" that relies on secrets (other than the key) is doomed.

Answer (score 1):

A single AES-256 encryption should be plenty strong enough.  4 sounds sufficiently paranoid.